# Using .split(","); to split .csv data into an array whilst in a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, split

This is a problem I am currently having. Here is my code:

```
String[] sArray = new String[maxEntries*2];

for (int i = 0; i != (maxEntries*2); i++)
{
    sArray[i] = lines[i].split(",");
}
```

And lines[] is an array that has already read the data from the .csv file
The previous code WOULD work if I replaced 'i' with 0, for example, but I need to split the data for the entire lines[] array.
However, I get the following error message repeatedly:

```
error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
            sArray[i] = lines[i].split(",");
                                      ^
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The error is crystal clear.. read it and fix it

Comment: But both are arrays? I'm splitting data from an array and putting it in another  array

Comment: `sArray[i]` is the `i-th` element of `sArray`. What kind of array did you declare? You declared an array of String. And what does the `String.split(...)` method return?

Comment: sArray[i] is String sArray is Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sArray` is an array of String, thus `sArray[i]` is a String.
The `split(String str)` method returns an array.

You are trying to give an array value to a string variable.
sArray must be an array of String arrays

Answer (score 1):

`split`  returns an array of `String`. If you want the first element, you can use `sArray[i] = lines[i].split(",")[0];`. Replace the `0` by `i` if you want to iterate on the columns.

What you're trying to do is probably:

```
String[][] myata = new String[maxEntries*2];

for (int i = 0; i != (maxEntries*2); i++)
{
    myData[i] = lines[i].split(",");
}
```

This way you'll get the data of every line in a string array, and these arrays are in a bigger array.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

```
 sArray[i] = lines[i].split(",");
```

to

```
sArray = lines[i].split(",");
```

Comment: It is a good observation, but then he won't loop on his data, he would erase it every time he loops.

Answer (score 0):

> Using .split(","); to split .csv data into an array whilst in a for
>   loop?

This is a compile time error i.e **String[] cannot be converted to String**
Because You are trying to assign a String array to a String variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i != (maxEntries * 2); i++) {
            String s = lines[i];
            sArray = s.split(",");
        }
```